# How can I make the code recognize several digits string?

Tags: python, conditional-statements, lexical-analysis

I have a code of a lexical analyzer but what I need is that it recognize a full string, because it only recognize one digit. This means: if the needed digit is 111 it will process it as 1, 1, 1, doing 3 processes instead of one. What I need is the code to recognize the full number (111) as a string

'''

```
#Function remove that eliminates spaces
def remove(word):
    return word.replace(" ", "")
     
#Dictionary that defines the type of tokens
lexical_category = {
"+":"Token lexical category: ADDITION",
"-":"Token lexical category: SUBTRACTION",
"/":"Token lexical category: DIVISION",
"*":"Token lexical category: MULTIPLICATION",
"%":"Token lexical category: MODULE",
}

input_array =  input("Please type the string to be evaluated: ")
c_array = remove(input_array)

for i in c_array:
    print("Given token:",i)
    
    e = i.isalpha()
    h = i.isdigit()

    if(e==True):
        print("Token lexical category: VARIABLE")
    elif(h == True):
        print("Token lexical category: CONSTANT")
    else:
        lexical_category2=lexical_category.get(i)
        print(lexical_category2)
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
import re
#Function remove that eliminates spaces
def remove(word):
    return word.replace(" ", "")

#Dictionary that defines the type of tokens
lexical_category = {
"+":"Token lexical category: ADDITION",
"-":"Token lexical category: SUBTRACTION",
"/":"Token lexical category: DIVISION",
"*":"Token lexical category: MULTIPLICATION",
"%":"Token lexical category: MODULE",
}

input_array =  input("Please type the string to be evaluated: ")
c_array = remove(input_array)

numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', c_array)
c_array = [i for i in c_array if not i.isdigit()]

for i in c_array:
    print("Given token:",i)
    
    h = i.isdigit()

    if(h == True):
        print("Token lexical category: CONSTANT")
    else:
        lexical_category2=lexical_category.get(i)
        print(lexical_category2)
for num in numbers:
    print(f'Given token: {num} \nToken lexical category: VARIABLE')
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are iterating over every character from the input string. Why don't you try the str.split() method to separate the input into chunks. Then you can iterate over each chunk.

```
eg, "hello there".split() -> ["hello", "there"]
eg, "415 + 92".split() -> ["415", "+", "92"]
```

This method would assume that each number, variable, and operator is spaced with " " (a space).

```
This means, "x*3".split() -> ["x*3"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! I checked out but still it doesnt work :c Because this time it recognizes numbers but the problem now goes to letters.  :c